# R programming Error

Tags: r

I am getting following error in R-Studio.

```
    > r <= rnorm(100)
Error: object 'r' not found
```

Can anybody provide input what must be wrong here.

```
R-Studio Version -> Version 0.99.485 
R-Version - 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) (Fire Safety)
```

Comment: Use `<-` The symbol you used means "equal or less than"

Comment: OMG!!!!! silly mistake.... :(

Comment: Indeed. Use the `help()` or `?` when you have an error, it will usually fix it. In `help('<=')` you would have seen that it was a relational operator and at the end of the help you would have seen that you should have used `<-`

Answer (score 2):

your code should be like:

```
> r <- rnorm(100)
```

you need to change the **<=** to **<-**